# HttpClient fails on Mac M1

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-mac

I have a blazor wasm app that I developed on a Windows PC in Visual Studio 2022. I've recently been trying out a MacBook Air M1, with Visual Studio 2022 for Mac Installed.

I copied the VS solution across. It compiles and runs ok until it gets to the following line in the code-behind of a page component:

```
return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<ClientOrg>>($"api/clients");
```

This should make a http request to a web api project of the same solution but instead, the following error is raised:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: '<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: '<' is an invalid start of a value

The same code works when run on Windows.

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The response you are seeing is a web page, (which all start with <html>).  If you output the content , rather than trying to decode it as JSON you will exactly what the problem is. I would guess that the HttpClient.BaseAddress hasn't been configured correctly, and you are requesting an API page that doesn't exist, and therefore the web server is returning an HTML error page.

Comment: Thank Neil, when I changed to _httpClient.GetStringAsync($"api/clients"); I could see the html page that was being returned. Problem is, it just says "An unhandled error has occurred". I don't the request is reaching the api, a breakpoint on that is never hit. Also, I've tried running a util like Fiddler called Proxyman and that shows no sign of an http request

Comment: The API is the one returning the HTML, so it must be hitting the server.  Maybe the server middleware is throwing an exception before it gets to the code where your breakpoint is.  If you run the server in debug mode, you should be able to see the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for you help Neil. It was a dumb mistake from me but your suggestion helped me get to the discovery

Answer (score 0):

The was a dumb mistake but I give myself some slack since this is the first time I've used a mac - Visual Studio for Mac is quite different!

The problem was that the blazor client project was set as the startup project. Once I'd switched to set the blazor server project as start then all worked just the same as when debugging the solution on Windows. I'm sure there'll be more hurdles to jump but so far I'm impressed with being able to build dotnet apps on a Mac with no Intel chip.